# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute') when using module.export

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to split the code for my discord.js bot into multiple js files for better organization and troubleshooting. When doing so, I chained my functions using module.exports linking multiple files together. Going from my index file to the first function file, everything works fine. Going to the second, I get a TypeError said above. I am not sure why this occurs but I think it may have to do with nesting multiple module.export commands?? Is there a solution/alternative to achieve this? I've looked at other questions on this site but I can't seem to find one with the same issue I am facing. Code below.

**message.js**

```
module.exports = {
name: 'message',
execute(client, message) {
    const{ commandinit } = require(`./commandinit.js`);
    if(message.content.startsWith("-") || !message.author.bot) {
        var commandObj = message.content.slice(2);
        command = commandObj.toLowerCase();
        commandinit.execute(client, message, command);
    }else{return;}},};
```

**commandinit.js**

```
module.exports = {
name: 'commandinit',
execute(client, message, command){
    //do this stuff
```

},};

Sorry if this is a stupid question, as you can tell I am very new with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `const{ commandinit } = require(`./commandinit.js`);` should be `const commandinit = require(`./commandinit.js`);` as you don't want the `commandinit` property of the exported object but he object itself.

Comment: I advise you format your code. It will really help you and everyone else debug